# Why the Lie group and its Lie algebra have the same action?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\phi$ be a $g$ equivariant vector valued function that is $\phi(p \triangleleft g)=g^{-1}\triangleright \phi(p)$ and $\phi(p) \in V$ where $V$ is some vector space.

Now let $g=\exp(At)$ be a matrix group where  $A$ is an element of its lie algebra. In this lecture
[Covariante derivatives](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClIVG7ilm_Q&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic&index=25&t=2450s&ab_channel=FredericSchuller)  Professor Schuller calculates the derivative
$$\phi(p \triangleleft \exp(At))'(0)=\exp(-At)'\triangleright \phi(p)(0)=-A\triangleright \phi(p)$$

My question why is that the action $\triangleright$ in  $\exp(-At)'\triangleright \phi(p)(0)$ is the same as action $\triangleright$ in $-A\triangleright \phi(p)$ ?

Comment: Because you are taking the derivative wrt $t$ and evaluate it at $t=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not, but it's related, so one often uses the same notation for both. In general, an action of a group $G$ on a vector space $V$ is a homomorphism $\Psi:G\to \operatorname{GL}(V)$, but instead of writing $\Psi(g)(v)$, we write $g\triangleright v$. The corresponding action of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} = T_eG$ on $V$ is the derivative of this map at the identity, i.e.
$$
T_e\Psi:T_e G\to T_I\operatorname{GL}(V)
$$
Now $T_I\operatorname{GL}(V)= \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is isomorphic to $L(V)$, the set of linear (but not necessarily invertible) maps on $V$. So we can say
$$
T_e\Psi:\mathfrak{g}\to L(V).
$$
Instead of writing $T_e\Psi(A)(v)$ for $A\in\mathfrak{g}$ and $v\in V$, the lecturer is writing $A\triangleright v$ for simplicity.

Comment: could you give me some reference please?

Comment: You could try "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations - Second Edition" by Brian Hall. Proposition 4.4 discusses the relationship between Lie group and Lie algebra representations. In Hall's notation, if $\Pi:G\to\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is the Lie group representation, then $\pi:\mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is the corresponding Lie algebra representation, and is given by $\pi(A) := \frac{d}{dt}\big\vert_{t=0}\Pi(e^{tA})$. This is an alternative way of saying $\pi = T_e\Pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $gl(n,C)$ be the **algebra** of complex matrix, $B$  a lie subalgebra of $gl(n,C)$  and $A$ the lie algebra of a matrix group $G$ where $G$ as set is contained in $gl(n,C)$.
Now suppose that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as a lie algebra and that $g(t)=\exp(bt)$ is a curve in $G \subset gl(n,C) $ with $b \in B$. So since $g(t)$ and $b$ are element of the same  algebra of matrices we can define the same action.

Note people often say that for matrix group  $\frac{d}{dt} \exp(At)(0)=A$, but we can not define this operation in a matrix group because in a matrix group there is no addition and so you have to go to the algebra of matrices  $gl(n,C)$ to define this operation